# Puppet Nginx Install CentOs

Tags: puppet

Can someone tell me why this is not working? This code works just fine on an Ubuntu server, but crashes on CentOS. I am running Puppet version `3.7.2`.

```
node default {
  package { 'httpd':
    ensure => 'absent'
  }

  package { 'nginx':
    ensure => 'installed',
    require => Package['httpd'],
  }
}
```

and I am getting this error:

```
Error: Execution of '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list nginx' returned 1: Error: No matching Packages to list
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[default]/Package[nginx]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Execution of '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list nginx' returned 1: Error: No matching Packages to list
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

nginx is not in the default CentOS repo; it requires `epel`. Before you can install the package, you need to require `epel-release`:

```
package { 'epel-release':
  ensure => 'installed',
}

package { 'nginx':
  ensure  => 'installed',
  require => [Package['httpd'], Package['epel-release']],
}
```

By the way, does your installation of nginx specifically require httpd being absent *before* installation?  You should be able remove the httpd metaparameter dependency.

Comment: I put it there because I had accidentally installed it. Thank you for this response. Is there a website I can reference for future questions like this? By that I mean when different OS's have package dependencies that others might not. Or any irregularities in general across OS's (sorry for the vagueness of this question)

Comment: If you had accidentally installed it you can remove it from the require statement as it will just uninstall at some point in your puppet run.  Re: preventing conflict... [librarian-puppet](https://github.com/rodjek/librarian-puppet) is useful for downloading and managing dependencies. It can also pin module versions to prevent conflicts.